# Enum with string value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Instead of having an `Enum` type where a unique value is given an enumerated value, for example:

```
class Bases(Enum):
    HEX     = 1
    OCTAL   = 2
    BINARY  = 3
    DECIMAL = 4
```

Is there a way to do something like the following instead?

```
class Bases(Enum):
    HEX     = '0x'
    OCTAL   = '0o'
    BINARY  = '0b'
    DECIMAL = ''
```

And then I could get something like:

```
<Bases.HEX: 0x>
```

Or, do I need to add a string method to 'fake' this? Or, at this point should I just create a `dict` instead?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) say `Member values can be anything: int, str, etc..`. Your code works for me. `Bases.HEX` -> `<Bases.HEX: '0x'>` Are you getting an error when you try this?

Comment: @MarkMeyer ah nice! I must've missed that in the docs -- they didn't show any examples with `str` type I don't think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class Bases(enum.Enum):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s.%s: %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self._name_, self._value_)
    HEX = "0x"
    OCTAL = "0o"
    BINARY = "0b"
    DECIMAL = ""

>>> Bases.HEX
<Bases.HEX: 0x>

>>> Bases('0x')
<Bases.HEX: 0x>
```

```
>>> class hstr(str):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         print("__repr__")
...         return super().__repr__()
...     def __str__(self):
...         print("__str__")
...         return super().__str__()
... 
>>> 
>>> s = hstr('Hello')
>>> print("%s" % s)
__str__
Hello
>>> print("%a" % s)
__repr__
'Hello'
>>> print("%r" % s) # default
__repr__
'Hello'
```

Comment: How is this different than the default `__repr__()`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer the only difference is this one doesn't surround the string with quotes (though not sure why it's needed) -- `<Bases.HEX: 0x>` vs. `<Bases.HEX: '0x'>` (default).

Comment: If the value is a `str` it should have quotes around it.